# Tomcat problem - Could not reserve enough space

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, heap-memory

I am running server with 256MB RAM. Maximum heap size I can allocate for Java is 110MB. When I add those param to JAVA_OPTS I can run java -version. Problem is that I can not run Tomcat with these parameters. Maximum heap size for Tomcat to run is 40MB. I do not know why I can not allocate more memory?

Of course I get error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Comment: Are you sure enough memory remains for this size of heap? Check free memory space on your server.

Comment: My main problem is: why I can not allocate 110MB to Tomcat heap size if I can do it for Java?

Answer (score 2):

Set `CATALINA_OPTS` to `-Xmx110m`, `JAVA_OPTS`. I suppose you could set both, to be sure.

Comment: I also tried setting CATALINA_OPTS to -Xmx110m and I get error.

Answer (score 2):

The `Xmx` flag may be ignored when you run the `java` executable with the `-version` flag. This depends on how you pass the version flag. The following are the results on my machine with 2GB RAM:

**Version flag passed before Xmx**

```
C:\Users\Reynolds>java -version -Xmx10240M
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)
```

which is weird considering that 10G is beyond the max addressable limit on memory in a 32-bit environment.

**Version flag passed after Xmx**

```
C:\Users\Reynolds>java -Xmx10240M -version
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx10240M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

C:\Users\Reynolds>java -Xmx1524M -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

which is closer to reality.

You might want to verify how much contiguous memory is available to Java in reality, using the second approach, and then decide on an optimal value for the maximum heap size.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that `java -version` doesn't actually create a JVM

Comment: @matt, no that is not the case. In the Oracle/Sun JVM, it actually executes the print() method of the `sun.misc.Version` class.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests you do not have enough free RAM try closing other applications and seeing if you can allocate a larger heap then. You may need more RAM I am afraid.

Comment: There is only one application on my server. No other processes are running.

Comment: that is strange what operating system are you running on?